# WPF DataGrid - Adding Rectangles to DataGrid cells in codebehind

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that is populated in Codebehind using its DataContext. So the columns are auto generated and the actual number of columns generated do change.

Ultimately I need to be able to display a barchart in the Cells (col) depending on the value of a cell in another field (Col + 1).

My initial thoughts are to add a rectangle and change its width to the percentage of the cell width based on the value in col + 1 - but I am failing to find where to start doing this entirely in code behind.

Has anyone done this or have any advice that might help me get to what I am looking for please?

I can give more information if required.

EDIT:

As Requested, I thought I would try and visualize what I am after better. So, my Datagrid is populated with data similar to the following:

[image]

where there are 3 sets of 2 columns (a Perc & Result column for 1, 2 & 3... This number could be up to anything!). Now, the value in the Perc column is referenced to conditionally control the style of rectangles that sit in the respective Result columns (in this example I am using colours to represent the percent. In reality I am looking to use the perc value to set the width of the coloured rectangle in the Datagrid cell to give a barchart appearance).

Finally, I will hide all the Perc columns so the results will look like:

[image]

Does that mke any more sense... I hope I havent confused things further??

Comment: I think you're going to have to add more information as this was quite confusing. Each column (col) is going to be "filled" based on the next column (col + 1)? That alone is pretty confusing. You may want to post a drawing of what you hope to be the end result.

Comment: I have just added a bit more detail... I hope this is more clear?